# Using Label for logging in a WindowsForm application sometimes results in an exception - why?

Tags: c#, label, windows-forms-designer

Is it allowed/discouraged to use a Label in a Windows Form application for displaying the application status?

At first I thought it would have been a wise idea, but now I realized I have many logs that do not display, and often crashes if I don't put a try/catch around the Label.Text change.
Here's the function I use.

```
private void Echo(string p)
{
    lock (m_syncObject)
    {
        try
        {
            InfoBox.Text = p.ToString();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also added a lock to multiple access to the same resource.
Can anyone explain why do I frequently end up in the 'catch'?

Comment: You really shouldn't swallow exceptions like that. Without seeing what they are, how do you expect to learn how to circumvent them? =)

Comment: Please find out what the exception being thrown is, and clarify your question with that. At the moment, any answer given would be based on speculation about the rest of the inner workings of your code. =)

Comment: Is your application multithreaded ? It is possible that `string p` gets null.

Comment: J.Steen I agree, but I knew that the snippet above would have been sufficient to find the issue. As expected, Petriuc solved it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfoBox.Text = p.ToString(); -> That can generate a cross-thread exception. Try this instead:

```
delegate void myDelegate(ref Label lb, string toAdd);
private void UpdateLabel(ref Label lb, string toAdd)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new myDelegate(UpdateLabel), new object[] { lb, toAdd });
    }
    else
    {
        lb.Text = toAdd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call `.ToString` on an string type variable. If your `p` is null, then you will get exception. You can simply do:

```
private void Echo(string p)
{
    lock (m_syncObject)
    {
        try
        {
            InfoBox.Text = p;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather, it's also likely a cross-thread exception... and I see someone else beat me to it. =)